# /user/{id}/timeline results leaking template used for badge information

Tags: bug, status-completed, timeline

From my [elections statistics](http://se.awio.com/election.html) page:

[image: Recent activities page showing $ChatUrl where the URL to the chat page should be]

I inserted in the `detail` field as plain text because I wasn't sure if the results would be HTML, but the `$ChatUrl` left in the anchor's `href` is surely a bug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah, that containing HTML at all is a bug.

Badge descriptions at the time of 1.0 freeze were all plaintext.  A fix for this will go out with the next API build, which should be tonight sometime.

Comment: This appears to be [broken again](https://api.stackexchange.com/2.1/badges/name?order=desc&sort=rank&inname=outspoken&site=stackoverflow&filter=!6KsxZNOyH.zSE).